# Setting Jquery Multiselect plugin properties from codebeind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to set jquery Multiselect plugin properties from codebeind?

I have created a asp.net web user control which shows multiselect jquery dropdown with checkboxes. I am using this control on different places on same page and want to adjust the width of each dropdown. Don't know if it is possible to have a control property in code behind which will change the width of multiselect dropdown.

```
$("select").multiselect({
   selectedText: "--Select ALL--",
   minWidth: '300'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert javascript in your page that can do that work, but you will need to know the `id` of each select element to do that.

But I wouldn't recommend this.

The best would be to set the property in your html rather than calling javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more info to [ppetrov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008409/ppetrov) answer, you can wrap javascript statements to a function. Like following

```
function SetSize(size)
{
 $("select").multiselect({
    selectedText: "--Select ALL--",
    minWidth: size
 });
}
```

In serverside code, you can use following to set size.

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "scrpt", string.Format("SetSize({0});","100"), true);`

Assuming you need to do this for all `select` element,as you have specified this in selector.

**But**, it is best practice to handle everything in clientside code ( JS) , since you need to handle something in JS.